# Rounding a float in c / objective-c. Errors when the last digit is a 5

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, floating-point, currency

**Simplified problem:**

I have a float `0.02275`, and when I round it to 4 decimal places, instead of the expected `0.0228` I get `0.0227`.  I know this occurs because the floating point value of `0.02275` is something like `0.0227499999999999...`, which when rounded to 4 decimal places gives `0.0227`.

```
float a = 0.02275;
NSLog(@"float a is %f",a);
NSLog(@"float a, rounded to 4 decimal places is %0.4f",a);
NSLog(@"float a, rounded to 10 decimal places is %0.10f",a);
```

gives output

```
float a is 0.022750
float a, rounded to 4 decimal places is 0.0227
float a, rounded to 10 decimal places is 0.0227499995
```

My question is: how do I round this correctly to get `0.0228` instead of `0.0227`?

**The real situation's limitations:**

The float is taken from a plist file; `NSNumber floatValue` is used while assigning it to variable `a`.

My program is dealing with money and percentages.  The money values are user input, and the percentages are either fixed, or user input.  The float in the example above is one of the percentage values causing inaccuracies in my calculations.

Comment: If you can't change the variable assignment, are you able to change the value in the plist file to be slightly higher, so that the internal representation falls on the "right" side of `0.02275`? It's a dodgy hack, but it might meet your needs.

Comment: Try to use [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) since you're dealing with money.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The format operator truncates; it doesn't round.</strike>

See the documentation for printf for details. %.4f does round, but 0.02775 rounds down to 0.0277 and that's what you see. I believe 0.027751 will give you the 0.0278 you expect.

Comment: I believe it's `roundf()`.

Comment: Are you sure the format operator truncates?  `float w = 8.8888;
    NSLog(@"w to 2dp is %0.2f",w);`  outputs `w to 2dp is 8.89`

Comment: My mistake: %.nf does round.   Edited above; my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use floats to store money values. Error will keep adding up, which generally is not desirable with money. Store money in integer as cents (or tenths of cents if you can have fractional cent amounts...). Also store percentages as integer too, like 100%=1000 or whatever accuracy you want.

Example:

```
$10 * 105% (logical)
= 1000 * 1050 (variable values)
= 1050000 (intermediate result)
/ 1000 (divide by numeric value of 100%)
= 1050 (final cent value)
= (double)1050/100.0 (C code to get dollars as double for printing)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected I might need to do this.  Was just hoping I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://www.accuretech.com/ios-app-development-rounding-number-tips/

It provides some other information too, but overall should help you to get what you need.